# What should I say to someone who is going into labor?

Tags: expressions

Today is the last day of my coworker before the expected day, which is tomorrow. What am I supposed to say to her? Can I say, "I wish you a safe delivery."?

Comment: There aren't set English sayings for every possible occasion. What is acceptable or appropriate to say will vary by culture and your relationship with the individual.

Comment: You can say "What a happy day!" because it should be. It does not suggest that the birth might have complications, be unhealthy, promote anxiety, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could say

> Best wishes for a healthy birth!

That is rather neutral and could apply for most cases, whatever your closeness with your colleague.

There are plenty of other expressions though, and they are all effective if they are sincere, so do not worry too much about the form of the wish.